# C++ homework compile error with if statement

Tags: c++

Having trouble with the second if statement to only read ten values. If I remove the program will compile. I need it in for the assignment I have tried several modifications, so what is here may not reflect my last attempt. C++ homework compile error with if statement. Details how many more details do I need to add before this will post, more details

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    /**********************************************************************
    * Get File
    * This function will prompt the user for the name of the file and
    * return it.
    *********************************************************************/

    void getFileName(char fileName[])
    {
        //prompt the user
        cout << "Please enter the filename: ";
        cin >> filename;

        ofstream fout(fileName);
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    * Read
    * This function will read the file and return the average score of the
    * ten values.
    *********************************************************************/

     float readFile(char fileName[])
     {
         cout.setf(ios::fixed);  //no scientific notation
         cout.precision(0);      //no decimals

         //In case of error
         ifstream fin(filename);
         if (fin.fail())
         {
             cout << "Error reading file \"" << fileName << "\"" << endl;
             exit(0);
         }

         float data;          //always need a variable to store the data
         float i = 0;         //don't forget to initialize the variable
         float gradeSum = 0;  
         float average;

         //Add up all the grades
         while (fin >> data)   //while there was not an error
         {
              gradeSum += data; //do the work
              i++;
         }

         // Hint: Make sure you only read ten values.
         if (i != 10)
         {
             //tell the user what happened
             cout < "Error reading file \"" << fileName << "\"" << endl;
             exit(0);
         }

         //Calculate average grade
         average = gradeSum / i;

         //Close file
         fin.close();

         return average;
     }

    /**********************************************************************
    * Display function
    * This function will display the average score to zero decimals of
    * accuracy.
    *********************************************************************/
    void display(float average)
    {
       cout << "Average Grade: " << average << "%" << endl; 
    }

    /**********************************************************************
    * main calls average grade and file name
    ***********************************************************************/
    int main()
    {
       char fileName[256];
       getFileName(fileName);

       int average = readFile(fileName);
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: To begin, please do not ask us to do your homework for you - the point of the assignment is for you to learn. Secondly, please do not pad your questions with garbage text, as it only makes your question harder to read.

Comment: And include the error, and only enough code to provide context.

Comment: There are more issues with this than just the error you point out. The first compilation error: `main.cpp:15:16: error: 'filename' was not declared in this scope cin >> filename;`. Compiler errors are *good*. The `15:16` means line 15 in your code, and 16 is the column in that line where the compiler is unhappy. Go there are see if you can do what the compiler wants.

Answer (score 2):

Note the position of your if statement in relation to your while loop. When does your if statement run? When does your while loop run?

With these in mind, how would you adjust your while loop to take into consideration your restriction (while loop stops executing when i = 10)?

I hope this helps you better understand what you need to do without spoiling too much of the answer.

P.S. The contents of the if block will quit the program on the spot if i != 10, without executing anything beyond.

```
if (i != 10)
     {
         //tell the user what happened
         cout < "Error reading file \"" << fileName << "\"" << endl;
         exit(0);
     }
```

Comment: That is my goal, only do the math and show the average and success statement when a file of ten numbers is averaged. Besides the typos, my real problem was not as I thought, it is the success statement does not get called out of void display(). If I comment it out and place in main() it works, except the math, I get an average of 1%, that is just the math which I can fix. I cannot satisfy the letter of the assignment unless I use the seperate function void display(). This is only my second question ever posted, thank you for not being hostile towards me.

Comment: @user9518506 No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow!
P.S. You can 'Accept' an answer for your question in addition to upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Simple typo with regards to the stream operator.

This line:

```
cout < "Error reading file \"" << fileName << "\"" << endl;
```

Should be:

```
cout << "Error reading file \"" << fileName << "\"" << endl;
```

Also, you have other typos preventing your code from compiling: namely the mixed case usage of `filename` and `fileName` throughout.  After I fixed those variable namings to be consistently `fileName`, it compiled.

Comment: I am aware of typos and mixed case usage, that came from making changes, pasting to notepad, making more changes, pasting to notepad and so on. I am not a fan of linux, where I can back out changes like other IDE's allow, but that is what I work with in this class. Have solved several issues, now my success statement does not appear from void display. If I place it in main() it works but not in it's own function. I call for it in main() void display(); but it does not seem to be called out. Thanks for your help, some others have only been grouchy at me on here, this is only my second question.

Answer (score 0):

your `cout` is invalid. `cout << "Average Grade: " << average << "%" << endl;` instead of `"cout < Average Grade: " << average << "%" << endl;`

Comment: I am aware of typos and mixed case usage, that came from making changes, pasting to notepad, making more changes, pasting to notepad and so on. I am not a fan of linux, where I can back out changes like other IDE's allow, but that is what I work with in this class. Have solved several issues, now my success statement does not appear from void display. If I place it in main() it works but not in it's own function. I call for it in main() void display(); but it does not seem to be called out. Thanks for your help, some others have only been grouchy at me on here, this is only my second question.

Comment: writing `void display();` will only declare a function. to call it do, `display();`.